# How to set up Doxygen and CMake for builds that generate headerfiles during the build process?

Tags: c++, cmake, doxygen

## Overview

Some of the header files in my CMake project are generated automatically during the build process. My goal is to setup `CMakeLists.txt` such that building the documentation for my project also triggers the header file generation (without triggering any other builds). The basic CMake/Doxygen setup follows the initial steps from this [MS tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clear-functional-c-documentation-with-sphinx-breathe-doxygen-cmake/).

## Details

The directory structure for this project is somewhat unconventional:

[image]

The `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` is `cmake/` holding the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, and `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` is `cmake/cmake-build-debug`.

[image]
[image]

I would like the generated documentation to end up in `cmake/cmake-build-debug/docs`. However, the CMake and Doxygen configurations I would like to commit to the repository so those files are in `docs/`.

The source files are as follows:

1. `squawk.cpp`:

   ```cpp
   #include "squawk.hpp"

   void squawk(const std::string &s) {
       std::cout<<STRFY(SQUAWK)<<": "<<s<<std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. `squawk.hpp`:

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   #define STRINGIFY(X) #X
   #define STRFY(X) STRINGIFY(X)
   #include "squawk.hd"

   void squawk(const std::string &s);
   ```
3. `main.cpp`:

   ```cpp
   #include "squawk.hpp"

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

       const std::string s = "Hello World!";
       squawk(s);

       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. `squawk.def`:

   ```cpp
   #define SQUAWK squeal
   ```

During the build process I take `squawk.def`, change `squeal` to `caw` and save it as `squawk.hd`, which is performed by `sed` and the instructions are in `squawk.ss`: `s/(#define SQUAWK)(.*)/\1 caw/`. This is the header file generation process. I want this to happen even if I just build the documentation without having to build the `squawk` binary.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The key in solving this issue was to use `add_custom_target` as opposed to `add_custom_command` for the header file generation.

1. `cmake/CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   ### Set variables ###
   set(SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src)
   set(SOURCES ${SRC_DIR}/squawk.cpp
       ${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp)
   set(SQUAWK_DEF ${SRC_DIR}/squawk.def)
   set(SQUAWK_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/squawk.ss)
   # Create include/ dir to save generated .hd file
   set(INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include)
   file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${INCLUDE_DIR})
   set(SQUAWK_HD ${INCLUDE_DIR}/squawk.hd)
   set(BIN_NAME squawk)

   ### Generate .hd file ###
   add_custom_target(gen_hd
           BYPRODUCTS ${SQUAWK_HD}
           DEPENDS ${SQUAWK_DEF}
           SOURCES ${SQUAWK_DEF} ${SQUAWK_SCRIPT}
           COMMAND sed --regexp-extended -f ${SQUAWK_SCRIPT} ${SQUAWK_DEF} >${SQUAWK_HD})

   ### Add target ###
   add_executable(${BIN_NAME}
       ${SOURCES}
       ${SQUAWK_HD})
   target_include_directories(${BIN_NAME} PUBLIC
       ${INCLUDE_DIR})

   ### Build documentation ###
   if(DOCUMENTATION)
       add_subdirectory(../docs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/docs)
   endif()
   ```
2. `docs/CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   ### Find Doxygen ###
   # We need Doxygen 1.9.2 or higher
   find_package(Doxygen 1.9.2 REQUIRED)

   ### Find headers ###
   get_target_property(SQUAWK_PUBLIC_HEADER_DIR ${BIN_NAME} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
   set(SQUAWK_PUBLIC_HEADERS "")
   foreach(d ${SQUAWK_PUBLIC_HEADER_DIR})
       file(GLOB_RECURSE SPH ${d}/*.h*)
       list(APPEND SQUAWK_PUBLIC_HEADERS ${SPH})
   endforeach()

   ### Set Doxygen variables ###
   # Set variables which will be subsituted
   # in the Doxyfile.in for INPUT and OUTPUT
   set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR "${SQUAWK_PUBLIC_HEADER_DIR}" "${SOURCES}")
   # Replace ; with space so string adheres to Doxygen syntax
   string(REPLACE ";" " " DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR "${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}")
   set(DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/docs")

   ### Generate Doxyfile ###
   # Use docs/Doxyfile.in and configure_file
   # to create cmake/docs/Doxyfile which will be used
   # to generate the documentation
   set(DOXYFILE_IN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile.in)
   set(DOXYFILE_OUT ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR}/Doxyfile)
   configure_file(${DOXYFILE_IN} ${DOXYFILE_OUT} @ONLY)

   ### Run Doxygen ###
   # Create directory where documentation will live
   # Specify index file which will be the output of the command
   # Add command and target
   file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR})
   set(DOXYGEN_INDEX_FILE ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR}/html/index.html)
       add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${DOXYGEN_INDEX_FILE}
               COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} Doxyfile
               MAIN_DEPENDENCY "${DOXYFILE_IN}"
               DEPENDS ${SQUAWK_PUBLIC_HEADERS} gen_hd
               WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR}
               COMMENT "Generating doxygen docs")
       add_custom_target(doxydocs
               ALL
               DEPENDS ${DOXYGEN_INDEX_FILE} ${SQUAWK_HD}
               WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR})
   ```

With the above set up building `doxydocs` will trigger `gen_hd` so that `squawk.hd` is generated. If we build `squawk` it will caw:

[image]